# Any downsides using '?' instead of L'?' with wchar_t?

Tags: c++, c, character, wchar-t

Are there any downsides to using `'?'`-style character literals to compare against, or assign to, values known to be of type `wchar_t`, instead of using `L'?'`-style literals?

Comment: I Don't think so since the standard says _A `char` array (whether plain `char`, signed `char`, or `unsigned char`), `char16_t` array, `char32_t` array, or `wchar_t` array can be initialized by a narrow character literal)_ but I will check more to make sure.

Comment: FYI, for "portable" characters, the rationale for allowing `'x' != L'x'` is to allow `wchar_t` to be Unicode even on systems where `char` has to be some EBCDIC character set. And when you consider a system, no matter how hypothetical, where that is the case, the question is immediately answerable: it can't be the same, so C (and hopefully C++ too) can't require them to be the same, and you must use `L'...'` character literals for `wchar_t`.

Comment: @hvd: Ohh... so `'x' == L'x'` is *bitwise* equality instead of *logical* equality?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand you correctly. `'x' == L'x'` compares the numeric values that correspond to the `x` character in `char` and `wchar_t`, and I *think* that's also what you mean?

Comment: @hvd: Ah, yes, that's what I mean -- so what I'm understanding is that you're saying if `x` is represented differently then their numeric values would be different, which would make them unequal... that's very interesting, thanks so much for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only downside is that your program might fail on stone-age systems using EBCDIC. On any real world system worth consideration, `char` and `wchar_t` values for the portable character set are all ASCII, and on increasingly many (but not all), `wchar_t` is a Unicode codepoint number.

Comment: Stone-age systems? A quick search gives BS2000/OSD 9.0, using EBCDIC, which was released in 2011.

Comment: I think I've heard (though only second-hand) that banks and such still use them.

Comment: There are some big players still using stone-age systems (maybe even the airline industry too...?), mostly IBM mainframes, but unless you're programming specifically for these machines, you probably don't have to care about them. It's unlikely most general-purpose code will run on them anyway. It's also unlikely anybody is using `wchar_t` on them...

Answer (score 6):

They have the wrong datatype and encoding, so that's a bad idea.  The compiler will silently widen character literals (for strings you'd get a type mismatch compile error), using the standard integral conversions (such as sign-extension).  But the value might not match.

For example, characters 0x80 through 0xff often map to different Unicode codepoints, and the exact mapping varies depending on the compiler's codepage.

Clearly, it's not possible for Unicode to map all the various codepages using an identity conversion.  **If merely widening were enough, there'd be no need for functions like `mbtowcs`.**

WRT your specific question about `'\xAB'` vs `L'\xAB'`, they probably are not equal.  See http://ideone.com/b1E39

Comment: lol I like how your answer turned from "yes" to "no" to "yes" in a couple minutes. :)

Comment: The question is not whether it will widen them or not but if the widening will always produce the correct `wchar_t` encoding

Comment: I don't even know if they *have* an "encoding" per se... though he removed that part.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying `'\xAB'` does *not* have to map to `L'\xAB'`?!

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah, I had the right answer first, then saw something in the Standard that surprised me, was about to quote it, then realized it was comparing the values of wide and wide characters, not wide and `char`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: `'\xAB'` won't map to `L'\xAB'`, because one has sign extension and one doesn't...  Also, special characters such as the British pound sign probably have different encodings between the narrow and Unicode character sets (depending on your source character set encoding, of course).

Comment: @BenVoigt `'\xAB'` won't necessarily have sign extension: it won't if `char` is unsigned. (Assuming C++, in which `'\xAB'` is a `char`. In C, it wouldn't even be sign extension, since `'\xAB'` is an `int`.)

Comment: @hvd: And you want to write code that only works if `char` is unsigned?  Mehrdad asked if it HAS TO.

Comment: @BenVoigt No, but I don't want to write code that only works if `char` is signed either, so I don't assume `'\xAB'` *won't* map to `L'\xAB'` either.

Comment: @hvd: Yeah, I like my wording in the answer better, but I can't change the comment any longer.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned, the standard says

> A char array (whether plain `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`), `char16_t` array, `char32_t` array, or `wchar_t` array can be initialized by a narrow character literal...

However, in the section for the `__STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__` preprocessor definition, it says

> The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that, in the encoding for `wchar_t`, a member of the basic character set need not have a code value equal to its value when used as the lone character in an ordinary character literal.

And for `__STDC_ISO_10646__`:

> An integer constant of the form yyyymmL (for example, 199712L). If this symbol is defined, then every character in the Unicode required set, when stored in an object of type `wchar_t`, has the same value as the short identifier of that character.

I am not exactly a professional at interpreting the standard, but I think that means the answer to your question is that they may have different representations, and you should always use the `L`.

Comment: Yes, C used to require that `L'?' == '?'`, then at one point that requirement was dropped, and `__STD_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__` was added so that programs can know whether they can still rely on the old guarantee.

Comment: I see nothing in the question that restricts values to the basic character set, and Mehrdad has been asking about 0xAB in the comments.

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry, I don't understand. What values?

Comment: @BenVoigt That ('\xAB')should have been in the question, IMO. `'?'` is in the basic character set, and it's obvious that when `wchar_t` is larger than `char`, that not all values can match, so this answer is a reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: Yes, I was just answering whether the short `'?'` can be different from the long `L'?'`

Comment: @hvd: I'm pretty sure that the question mark is a placeholder.  Hence the "-style" modifier.